# TouchableOpacity block during async calls #Performance React-native

Tags: android, performance, react-native, axios, redux-saga

i have fully working react-native android app [Groww](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.nextbillion.groww&hl=en) .Working on performance optimisation .

I am using Redux-saga & axios for async network call ,during network calls touchable opacity doesn't work ,everything work but clickable event doesn't responed.

I have optimised my application by using Flatlist , shouldComponentUpdate etc . but with this issue i am stuck any help would be appreciated.

Comment: It sounds like the native execution thread or the js<->native bridge are blocked for some reason. Are you reading large amounts of response data? Please post relevant code and perhaps that'll illuminate something. Alternatively, you can try using the button components from https://github.com/kmagiera/react-native-gesture-handler#buttons that handle the touch events on the native thread without JS interaction

Comment: I'm also facing this issue. Have you found any solution?

Answer (score 0):

You can enable Hermes in android/app/build.gradle. maybe this can help you.

```
project.ext.react = [
        entryFile   : "index.js",
        enableHermes: true,  // clean and rebuild if changing
]
```